# this error keeps showing up (discord.py categories error)

Tags: discord.py

I want help because I don't want my help command with no categories
code:

```py
class Base64(dccmds.Cog):
  @bot.command(pass_context=True)
  async def b64encode(ctx, string):
    string_b = string.encode("utf-8")
    await ctx.send(b64.b64encode(string_b).decode("utf-8"))
  @bot.command()
  async def b64decode(ctx, string):
    string_b = string.encode("utf-8")
    await ctx.send(b64.decodebytes(string_b).decode())
bot.add_cog(Base64())
```

I am getting this error:

[image: strong text]

I tried everything I could, but still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, you're registering the command twice. First, you add it with `bot.command()`, and then you add it a second time in the cog, causing the error.

The command should be added only once:

```py
class Base64(commands.Cog):

    @commands.command()  # this does not add the command, so it gets added later when you add the cog
    async def b64encode(self, ctx, string):
        string_b = string.encode("utf-8")
        await ctx.send(b64.b64encode(string_b).decode("utf-8"))

    @commands.command()
    async def b64decode(self, ctx, string):
        string_b = string.encode("utf-8")
        await ctx.send(b64.decodebytes(string_b).decode())

client.add_cog(Base64())
```

Comment: ok thx but why did you add self in bot commands?

Comment: It's necessary because the cog is a class, so python will pass the `self` for you. If you just do `ctx, string`, then you'll get an error because the context got passed into `string`.

Comment: still gives me an error

Comment: What's wrong? Can you send the traceback and some more code? It works for me.

Comment: it just gives me the same error

Comment: Have you defined that command elsewhere? Can you send all of the code?

Comment: sorry for the waiting i fixed it somehow